# How to get index of changed array under $watch in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, watch

I am using an array of objects

```
({"code":"id1","color":"red","description":"eg1"})
```

where each object contains input fields.User can dynamically add and remove those objects.
Now I want that when he enters code rest of the field should be filled automatically.
For that I have developed an algorithm which will take the code and will give me the color and description but for that I need the POSITION of the object which is changed so that I can update the array on that index itself.
Below is my share of code:

```
<div v-for="(x,i) in fabric_arr">
                <!--<pre>{{x}}</pre>-->
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <span>
                      <input type=”text” list="idOfDatalist" class="form-control  border-input" placeholder="Fabric Code" v-model="x._id">
                        <datalist id="idOfDatalist">
                           <option v-for="y in all_fabrics">{{y._id}}</option>
                        </datalist>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <span>
                      <input type=”text”  class="form-control border-input"  placeholder="Fabric Color" v-model="x.color"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                 <span>
                      <input type=”text” class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Fabric Description" v-model="x.description"></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

And my controller:

```
 watch: {
      fabric_arr: {
        handler : function (val) {
          console.log("val");
          console.log(val);
          //val.color="red always";
          this.fabric_arr[0].color="fghjkl"
        },
        deep: true
      }
    }
```

Comment: atleast tell why you downvoted?.lol

Comment: What if you try with a global variable, which keeps the modified index? and is good practice to bind :key to the v-for, if you have array manipulation.

Comment: @Akshay does the watch code in your question work without error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all those who are looking for the answer,use v-bind:change() to trigger the changes and manipulate index there.
Below is the code:

```
<input type=”text” list="idOfDatalist" class="form-control  border-input" placeholder="Fabric Code" v-model="x._id" v-bind:change="inpChangedForCode(x)">
                        <datalist id="idOfDatalist">
                           <option v-for="y in all_fabrics">{{y._id}}</option>
                        </datalist>
```